# Why if for V <: Seq[Int] when V is a Seq descendant map and zip operations return a Seq[Int]

Tags: scala

As mentioned in the title i don't understand why these function doesn't compile and are asking for a Seq.

```
def f1[V <: Seq[Int]](v: V): V = v.map(_ + 1)
def f2[V <: Seq[Int]](v: V): V = v.zip(v).map{ case (a, b) => a + b }

error: type mismatch;
found   : Seq[Int]
required: V
```

I have the following workaround :

```
def f1[V <: Seq[Int]](v: V): V = v.map(_ + 1).asInstanceOf[V]
def f2[V <: Seq[Int]](v: V): V = v.zip(v).map{ case (a, b) => a + b }.asInstanceOf[V]
```

But i would like to know if it exist another solution. If not what is the cost of casting something like that, is it O(1) or O(n) with n the Seq size.

Answer (score 2):

Because

```
v.map(_ + 1).asInstanceOf[V]
```

can easily fail: `map` is only guaranteed to return a `Seq[Int]`, which may or may not happen to be an instance of `V` when you run the code.

One example would be `V = SeqView.Filtered`, where `map` returns a `SeqView.Mapped`.

> If not what is the cost of casting something like that, is it O(1) or O(n) with n the Seq size.

The cost of casting with `asInstanceOf` is always O(1). In some cases it's actually a no-op and the cost is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through how your function is compiled:

```
def f1[V <: Seq[Int]](v: V): V = v.map(_ + 1)
```

1/ You declared `V` as a sub-type of `Seq[Int]`. So `V` can be viewed by the compiler as `Seq[Int]`. 
 
2/ Inside function, `v.map(_ + 1)` return type is `Seq[Int]` because it's using a `Seq` method. 
 
3/ `V` is the declared return type. This doesn't match the actual return type, which is `Seq[Int]`. And your compiler can't view `Seq[Int]` as `V` because because there's no type bound that says `[V >: Seq[Int]]`.

Comment: "And your compiler can't view Seq[Int] as V because it contradicts with 1/" No, 1 doesn't matter here, it's just that it has no reason to think `Seq[Int]` is a subtype of `V`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov that's what I meant, there's no type bound from `Seq[Int]` to `V`. But the reason why there's no standard way to express the type bound is because it will create infinite loop.

Comment: Actually, there is a standard way: `V >: Seq[Int] <: Seq[Int]`. Nothing contradictory or infinite-loop about it, if you change the definitions to use that they will compile. Nothing useful either, of course :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the trick :). Just to clarify, from the compiler perspective, does this mean they are the same type ?

Comment: `V` and `Seq[Int]`? I think reflection could distinguish them, but otherwise they should be, e.g. `implicitly[V =:= Seq[Int]]` will compile.

Comment: "Nothing useful either, of course :)" Just to clarify: of course specifying both lower and upper bounds can be useful, only the case when they are the same isn't.